# Why isnt it translating the digits to letters?

Tags: python-3.x

```
code = {
        "1": "a",
        "2": "b",
        "3": "c",
        "4": "d",
        "5": "e",
        "6": "f",
        "7": "g",
        "8": "h",
        "9": "i",
        "10": "j",
        "11": "k",
        "12": "l",
        "13": "m",
        "14": "n",
        "15": "o",
        "16": "p",
        "17": "q",
        "18": "r",
        "19": "s",
        "20": "t",
        "21": "u",
        "22": "v",
        "23": "w",
        "24": "x",
        "25": "y",
        "26": "z",
        " ": (),
    }
number = ["22", "22", "12", "23", "1"]
number2 = " ".join(number)
for letter in number2:
    number3 = code[number2]
print(number3)
```

Im pretty new in this coding stuff so sorry if this isnt the normal question format
I tried to build something to translate digits into letter but it is giving me key errors and now i dont know how do fix it myself ^^

Comment: In your for loop, you're using `number2` instead of `letter` as the index into `code`.

Comment: but if i use letter, i get an "a" as output. That isnt even the translation for the first digit of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do either of them

```
for letter in number2:
    number3 = code[letter]
print(number3)

OR

for letter in number2:
    number3.append(code[letter])
print(number3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are wanting to do something more like this?

the `number` list is used as keys to grab from the `code` dictionary. Then you append that found value to the `number3` list. Then print the `number3` list

```
code = {
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": "c",
    "4": "d",
    "5": "e",
    "6": "f",
    "7": "g",
    "8": "h",
    "9": "i",
    "10": "j",
    "11": "k",
    "12": "l",
    "13": "m",
    "14": "n",
    "15": "o",
    "16": "p",
    "17": "q",
    "18": "r",
    "19": "s",
    "20": "t",
    "21": "u",
    "22": "v",
    "23": "w",
    "24": "x",
    "25": "y",
    "26": "z",
    " ": ()
}
number = ["22", "22", "12", "23", "1"]
number3 = []
for letter in number:
    number3.append(code[letter])
print(number3)
```

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly it. Thank you now i just have to understand why yours work xD
But thanks you really helped me